# C Array program is crashing with segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning array and just wrote this small program to see how it works. but its crashing with segmentation faul which i understand mean i am writing my variable / function to an memory place not allotted to it. But I cant figure how. Can anyone let me know please? 
i am calling introArray from my main().

```
int introArray (void)
{
    int total, ctr;

    printf("enter how many students \n");
    scanf("%d", &total);

    int students[total];
    ctr = 0;

    while ( students[ctr] <= total)
    {
        printf("enter student %d DOB in mmddyy \n", ctr );
        scanf("%d", students[ctr]);
        ctr++;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Which compiler are you using to build this program?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, there is one implementation logic issue. The total number of students is `total` and hence, your `while` loop should be

```
while(ctr < total)
```

The data to be read also should `scanf("%d", &students[ctr]);` There is an *ampersand* missing

Comment: thanks ganesh. I made the recommended changes and its still crashing with same segementation fault error. Any idea why?? Also, why is ampersand needed when i am dereferencing with [] ??

Comment: @user2152138 If you haven't used _ampersand_ then there is a likelihood that your code will crash. When you dereference an array element as `students[ctr]`, then you are actually accessing the corresponding value. However, your objective is to read a value through `scanf` and for this you need to pass the `address` of the element. Hence, you should use `&students[ctr]`.

Answer (score 0):

`ctr` goes beyond `total`. This way you are going out of bound
Change the loop to

```
while (ctr < total)
{
        printf("enter student %d DOB in mmddyy \n", ctr );
        scanf("%d", &(students[ctr]));
        ctr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
while ( students[ctr] <= total)
```

is not protection against reading past your array bounds inside the loop. This will stop you reading past the end of your array provided you use `ctr` as your index

```
while ( ctr < total)
```

you need the strict inequality as array indices are zero based.

In addition, your `scanf` call inside your `while` loop is wrong - the second argument should be a pointer and currently you pass an integer. It should be

```
scanf("%d", &students[ctr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
scanf("%d", students[ctr]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &students[ctr]);
```

Comment: @Armin Only the second one is right.  In the first snippet scanf would try to write at address students[ctr], which is some garbage value (or maybe zero, depending on the compiler).  In the second snippet scanf will write at the address of the ctr element of the students array, which is correct.